# How do Clone Troopers tell each other apart in battle?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, clones

How do Clone Troopers without unique markings tell each other apart in battle? Clone Officers and even Jedi seem to be able to distinguish individual basic Clone Troopers (plain white armor, or armor otherwise adopted by the whole unit) by name during battle.

Perhaps clones have a HUD system that has tags on each clone, but then how do the Jedi tell them apart?

Comment: Fairly certain that in the parts you're talking about the Jedi are usually referring to a higher ranking Clone Trooper, these Troopers seem to have different coloured shoulder pads to denote their rank and thus serve as an identifier.

Comment: How does a Jedi- The Force. Next question!

Comment: They only look alike to *us.*

Answer (score 12):

As far as Jedi telling them apart, the canon answer is in the Season 1, Episode 1 of of *Clone Wars* cartoon ("*Ambush*"). Predictably, the answer is "The Force" :)

Yoda tells the clones he's with to take off their helmets while resting so he can look at their faces.

They object that there's no point as they all look identical.

Yoda tells them that indeed they are all different inside, and proceeds to Jedi-psychoanalyze each one in turn.

> **Yoda**: Come, sit.
>   Your helmets, remove them.
>   Your faces I wish to see.
>
> **Clone Trooper**: There's not much to look at here sir.
>   We all share the same face.
>
> **Yoda**: Deceive you, eyes can.
>   **In the force, very different each one of you are.**
>   Rys, always focuse on the enemy, are you. For inspiration, look to yourself, and those beside you.
>   Jeck, concerned about weapons you are. Weapons do not win battles. Your mind, powerful it is. Outthink the droids, you can.
>   Thire, rush not into fights, Long is the war, Only by surviving it, will you prevail.
>   Yes.
>   **Clones you may be, but the force resides in all life forms.**

I don't recall specific examples of clone troopers telling each other apart during combat, but that also makes perfect sense - they are all trained for individual missions and positions, so you know who the dude on the heavy blaster is from the dude assigned to the flank.

Comment: Legends now, but in the Republic Commando series, Etain Tur-Mukan says much the same of clones and how she can tell them so easily apart without looking a their faces.

Comment: So... the clone helmets block the force?  :)

Comment: no? but yoda just wanted to see their faces so they feel like individzals than clones

Answer (score 0):

Their fellow troopers use the HUD of their helmet's visor to differentiate the individual clones, while the Jedi use the Force to see the individual's unique soul.

Comment: Could you add some support for this?